# Looking for ideas for attaching handles to a low profile planter that serves as cover for an irrigation system manifold

Tags: irrigation

I have an Orbit manifold which I just installed. The pictures you will see below do not show the final state of the whole thing ...this is work in progress.

In the pictures below you can see that instead of buying one of the overpriced Orbit manifold boxes I build one using tiles and PL adhesive. The idea of this design is that the cover, which you see in place and on the side in the second picture, will serve as a planter for ground cover. This is designed to hide the manifold box. So that cover/planter is 17"x18"x1.5", it will be filled with soil and ground cover (same as what is currently around the box. With these being said and done, the cover/planter will become a little heavier and I am thinking that for easy access I should add some handles. Right now I am inclined to glue some nylon rope on the back side of the planter like in the  third picture

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Will the ground cover be cut/mowed?  Rope loops might get cut if left above ground.

Comment: no it will not be mowed

Comment: make the cover larger than the box ... that way you can lift it by the edges

Comment: IMO running the rope loop under the panel will be better than affixing it to the top, if the assy is of significant weight.  How heavy are the intended tiles?

Comment: That is what the third picture is showing...the rope glued to the back side of the cover

Comment: @jsotola it is already la4ger. The poin here is that it is too heavy

Comment: I would go with plastic covered landscaping wire instead of using rope.  also  that garden hose isn't intened to run at house water pressure 24/7. you'll probably need to upgrade that.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right -I need to sort that out. (garden hose at 24/7). That box is around a corner and on the other side of the corner there is a patio that I would need to dig under in order to properly install PVC pipe as for the rest of the system. Could a steel hose solve the problem ? https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=steel+hose 
Between the patio and the house I have a 1/2 gap where I could put 1/2 copper pipe lightly buried under 1/2in of gravel. That is the other solution that I have in mind